# Restarting Webservice running in a CMD-window with a simple script

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I have a webservice running in a cmd window on a server.
I have no access to directly interfer with it, other than going into the window and stopping in manually (with ctrl+c) and starting it again.

The task was to restart it at certain times. So to properly close I select the window, maximize it, send ctrl+c, wait until the confirmation pops up and confirm with "J" (this is not wrong, it's a german client) and ENTER.
Then Wait a bit and start it with the provided bat again.

Here's the script:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

shell.AppActivate "Administrator:  WebGui"

wscript.Sleep 5000
shell.SendKeys "% x"
wscript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys "^C"
wscript.Sleep 60000
shell.SendKeys "J"
wscript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
wscript.Sleep 10000

shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\webapps\web_gui"
shell.Run "runWebGui.bat"

wscript.Sleep 10000
shell.SendKeys "% n"
```

Manually everything works, but the moment I use the Task-Schedular or a script to let it be done automatically, it doesn't seem to work.

Here the script I tried to use in place of the Task-Schedular.

```
 'timer.vbs
 Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

 Do
      Wscript.Sleep 1000
      If Time() = TimeValue("6:45:00 AM") Then 
           objShell.Run "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /B /nologo C:\login\g-restart.vbs"
           Wscript.echo "Neustart um 6:45 gestartet"
      ElseIf Time() = TimeValue("12:00:00 PM") Then 
           objShell.Run "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /B /nologo C:\login\g-restart.vbs"
           Wscript.echo "Neustart um 12:00 gestartet"
      ElseIf Time() = TimeValue("5:00:00 PM") Then 
           objShell.Run "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe /B /nologo C:\login\g-restart.vbs"
           Wscript.echo "Neustart um 17:00 gestartet"
      End If
 Loop
```

I both cases it seems like the issue lies with AppActivate and then sending keys, when it's not done manually. Since the key-presses aren't sent towards the active window, but towards whatever is in the foreground...

So I assume the issue lies somewhere in here:

```
shell.AppActivate "Administrator:  WebGui"

wscript.Sleep 5000
shell.SendKeys "% x"
wscript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys "^C"
wscript.Sleep 60000
shell.SendKeys "J"
wscript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Is there any easy solution to my problem?

Comment: If the "J" simply stops the program, why not use `taskkill` to stop it, then start a new shell running it? If the program is capturing SIGINT (Ctrl-C) and doing some shutdown after "J" is entered, then `taskkill` might leave things in a bad state.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. `taskkill` might cause problems. Ctrl+C is the shutdown command, J is just the confirmation.